Entra OpenID - Client can't connect to API using the same authority and client
I am following the information from this youtube video by Nick Chapsas.
I have the following set up as described:
API
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(a =>
{
    a.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    a.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    a.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(b =>
{
    b.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Key"]!)),
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
    };
});

With appsettings.json:
"JwtSettings": {
  "Issuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/089e76d9-be81-46e6-9249-325211a2cc67/v2.0",
  "Audience": "5e7c53f0-527f-440c-8be2-34dccc1513ef",
  "Key": "myRegisteredApplicationSecret"
}

Where 089e76d9-be81-46e6-9249-325211a2cc67 is the (fake) tenantid.
and 5e7c53f0-527f-440c-8be2-34dccc1513ef is the (fake) clientid of the registered application on EntraID.
Client
For now I am using Postman to try and get authentication running. As mentioned by Nick I call my endpoint:
https://localhost:7049/WeatherForecast
And set header to:

I hid everything after ey but it's the full JWT token that I received from my Front End colleague.
That token was requested upon sign in against the same Issuer. It's defined like this on the Blazor WASM app:
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "ClientId": "5e7c53f0-527f-440c-8be2-34dccc1513ef",
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/089e76d9-be81-46e6-9249-325211a2cc67/v2.0",
    "ValidateAuthority": true
  }
}

It's supposed to work according to my colleague, but I still get
401 Unauthorized
As the result of my Postman request.
I have tried removing those Validate* tokenValidationParameters, to see if setting it less strict works but that's not the case.
My question

Am I missing something?
Is there a way to generate a token myself and see if I can get it to work with that?

Any good sources on how to set this up properly? Too many claim an easy solution but only explain 1/10th of the process. And piecing everything together out of all the existing (and almost equal but just different enough) options is very hard.

Remove bearer from your token value.

@GHDevOps so just ey...? No difference.

Looks like your issuer is AD B2C based on your login url. Is the API registered in Azure?

The video you referred to is adding JWT authentication and authorization into asp.net core application, but what you are trying to do is integrating Azure AD into asp.net core web api so that the API could be secured by AAD, and the frontend Blazor WASM app could use an access token to call the API. Please note, the API permission is the value of scope claim in access token and this is used for token valiation. It's important.
Therefore, we need to add AAD authorization scheme into asp.net core web api at first, and then we should integrate AAD authentication into blazor web assemebly app so that user could sign in with their microsoft account and generate required access token.
Let's follow this tutorial to secure our web api. We can also refer to this sample. Basically, there're 2 steps, we need to configure in Azure AD portal(create an Azure AD application, expose an API, add API permission, create client secret, add redirect url, see details in the tutorial) and we need to change our api Codes. Let's create a new .net 8 web api and choose Microsoft Identity platform as the authentication type. Then going to appsettings.json to modify AAD related configurations.

"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "tenant_id",
  "TenantId": "tenant_id",
  "ClientId": "azure_ad_client_id",
  "Scopes": "API_name_of_your_exposed_API",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},

Then let test the API with auth code flow.
Firstly, trying request below to get the auth code
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=client_id
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=redirect_url_you_set
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid
&state=12345
&nonce=abcde

Then you will see the auth code in the browser url field, copy and paste to use it to generate access token. The request url can be obtained in the link I shared above and please see my test. With this token in request header, I can reach the API successfully.


Decode the token, we can see the scopes we configured in the api, which is also the one we exposed in AAD and added the API permission.


Now the API is well-configured. Since there's no official sample for generating Access token, I find a workaround based on this document which using IAccessTokenProvider. Let's create a new .net 8 blazor web assembly application and choose Microsoft Identity platform as Authention type.

Then let's inject @inject IAccessTokenProvider TokenProvider in FetchData.razor and generate an access token.
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("sample-data/weather.json");
    var result = await TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken(new AccessTokenRequestOptions
        {
            Scopes = new[] { "api://client_id_exposing_api/Tiny.Read" }
        });
    if (result.TryGetToken(out var token))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {token.Value}");
        var res = token.Value;
    }
}


Don't forget to modify appsettings.json, we need to set client id and tenant id too.

About the blazor part, I only found this link which is used for calling MS Graph API, but no code samples for calling custom API.

Awesome, I'll look into it.

For Scopes, you mention "API_name_of_your_exposed_API", I registered a test app OIDC Authentication, so that name?

Hi, please see this case for how to expose an API and how to add api permission.  In my case, when I expose an API, I create a scope which name is Tiny.Read, so that the API permission should look like api://xxxx/Tiny.Read, and the "API_name_of_your_exposed_API" I mean is Tiny.Read
